# Jenkins: gradlew.bat tries to download gradle

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

I have setup a Job on my local system in Jenkins, everything is working fine here. Now I am trying to setup similar Job on a VM. On VM everytime gradlew.bat tries to download gradle 2.14. What to do?

I have my Gradle 2.14 downloaded and mapped to environment variable.

Comment: If using gradlew, it is expected behavior that it downloads gradle itself. To use local gradle distribution, you should stop using gradle wrapper, and use gradle directly

Comment: I tried the same, but getting this error:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'LocationSensing'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2.
     Required by:
               :<ProjectName>:unspecified

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you update `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` to point to the file path

```
distributionUrl=file\:/tmp/gradle-2.14-bin.zip
```

Comment: I tried it: 
distributionUrl=file\://C:/JenkinsSetup/gradle-2.14.1-all-bin.zip   distributionUrl=file\://C:/JenkinsSetup/gradle-2.14.1-all/gradle-2.14.1/bin     distributionUrl=file\://C:/JenkinsSetup/gradle-2.14.1-all/gradle-2.14.1
Still getting same issue, with all three tries